# Translate Group ID Principal SID to readable name

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

The ID starts with "S-1-5-21" I want to simply translate this whole ID so that I can get a better understanding of what the real group name is. 
This also only happens to security groups.

I tried this:

```
$Name = "S-1-5-21-2068335789-*********-1256946392-1001"(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($Name)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).value`
```

but it generates the error:

> "Exception calling "Translate" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identityreferences could not be translated."

This id is coming from a shared folder under security group or user name:

[image: screen shot link of what I'm talking about]

Comment: This probably means that your ActiveDirectory is inconsistent and needs to be cleaned up and made consistent. Normally, the technique you've used is enough to get the account name of the SG/user/computer, but when we've seen the same thing in our enterprise, it's meant that something was deleted, probably improperly, and the SID won't resolve (otherwise it would have resolved and you would have seen the group name instead of the SID).

Comment: so there is no way for me to track the SID by running a command and clean up AD by removing these SID if its not needed? how can I be sure these security groups may be deleted and got converted to SID?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is an 'orphaned SID' most likely from a user account that has been deleted from AD.

Folder ACLs (permissions) are not removed along with the user account. The permissions still contain the entry for that account which is displayed as its SID as it cannot be resolved to a human-readable name like the other objects

There's a nifty tool called [SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2012/07/finding-removing-orphaned-sids-in-file-permissions-or-busting-the-ghosts-built-into-windows-7/) that can find and remove these entries for you.

Comment: If i delete the orphaned SID from the shared folder security group, as seen in the picture i uploaded, does it affect anything in AD. Also, how sure are we that this orphaned SID is definitely disabled/deleted user accounts and not security groups??

Comment: "how sure are we that this orphaned SID is definitely disabled/deleted user accounts and not security groups" - it doesn't matter. The security principal no longer exists in the directory. That's why the access control list viewer shows a SID rather than the security principal's name.

Comment: As Bill said there is no need to check... unless your AD environment is in a seriously bad state and cannot resolve SIDs, but then you have much more to worry about than file/folder permissions!

Comment: okay thanks guys!. Im trying to get better understanding. so when a groupname/username gets converted to SID, it definitely means that the account is deleted.so if i delete that SID from the security list, will whoever had permission to that folder loose the permission that they had. My overall goal is to clean up these SID from these share folders and make proper security groups. ex. RW(read,write) RO(read only).

Comment: All permissions are saved as SIDs on the underlying NTFS Filesystem, Windows looks up and displays the object name (user/group/computer) as us humans prefer a name rather than a long series of numbers like a SID. It will only display the SID if the objects name cannot be resolved like when the object doesn't exist. So.. if you see a SID alongside other objects that are being displayed correctly, the SID is likely to be doing nothing at all.

Comment: Object name doesn't display even the AD entry still exists. Some existing or new AD object unable to display their object name instead it is showing the SID on the folder security tab. what will be the root cause if shared folder is unable to resolve the SID and translate it to human readable name

Comment: As I've said before, if the object doesn't exist its SID cannot be resolved.

Comment: So coming back to this thread. I tested by creating a group in AD for a specific folder and added the group to the security group and after 10-15 min it showed SID of readable name. The group i created still exists in AD but in the security group under the folder it gets translated to SID. Can it be caused the storage shared (SMB) ?